# The Footer and header will not allow me to position any of contend on the site

Tags: html, css

when I try to add in h3 onto the website it just stay at the top I tried to use position, top,left in the CSS but it doesn't want to response to it. I also tried to use a gallery template from w3schools to see if it will let me move the gallery but still no luck. I have tried to research this but I had no luck at all. sorry for the long code.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="sheet.css">
<head>
<title> Jon Barton </title> 
</head>
<header>
<ul class= "nav-men">
<li><a HREF="Gallery.html"> Gallery</a> </li>    
<li><a HREF= "JB.html">About me</a> </li>
<li><a HREF= "contractme.html"> Contract me</a></li>
</ul> 
<h1><span> Software Developer </span> </h1>
<p class = "kicker" >Ideas // Desinger //  Implement  </p>
</header>
<body>
<h3> Work</h3>
<footer>
<div class = "footer">
<div class ="content-wrap">
<ul>
<li><a href=  "Gallery.html "> </a></li>
<li><a href = "JB.html"> </a></li>
<li><a href= "contractme.html"> </a></li>
</ul>
<p class = "copyright"> All content copyright 2016</p>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

The css is a bit long sorry and some of it is just repeated.

```
  #css 
  header {

background: url(.//277H.jpg) ; 
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
  }

.nav-men li {
display:inline;
margin-left: 100px ;

}


 .nav-men  ul{ 


 margin: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none; 

}



     .nav-men  a {
            color:white;
 } 



  .nav-men   a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active
   {
text-decoration: none;
 } 


h1 {
font-size: 60px; 
color: white;
letter-spacing: 0.05em;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 700;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

 span {
  display: inline-block;
 padding: 0.2em  0.6em ;
 border: white solid 10px;
 }


 .kicker {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  color: white;
   }




   body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   }


    .alt-selction {
      background: black;
       }

   .thumb-container {
max-width: 980px  ;
margin: 0px auto ;
padding-bottom: 100px;
      }

 .thumb-unit {
  display:block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  float:left ;
   }



  .footer {
  margin: 30px;
  background: url(../277H.jpg) ;
  width:  100%;
  height: 100px;
  clear: both;
  bottom: -53px;
  left:-30;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  }

  .content-wrap {
     float: left;
  }


 li {       
display:inline;
margin-left: 100px ;
}


ul{ 

 margin: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none; 

}

 a {

    color:white;


}


  a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active  {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the position of the `<header>` and `footer` is absolute.
`position:absolute` positioned an element relative to the nearest positioned ancestor instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed.(from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp))

Remove the `position:absolute` from the class `header` & `.footer`. Then it will let you put anything between them.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial to have a sticky footer: 
[https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/]

After just add div at the top as a Header and you can add as many content between them after.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first cleaning up a bit of your HTML to put your header and footer inside the `body` element, and closing your body element properly as otherwise you will most probably run into other problems.

See this fiddle for an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/jowxoaca/1/

Also, as jonju mentioned, removing the `position:absolute` for header and footer would fix your ordering issue.